# Virtualized Windows memory speed on M1

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, virtualization, parallels-desktop, apple-silicon

I run Windows 10 on i9 MBP through Parallels and I see memory speed stuck at 667MHz.

How it is on M1 macs, also 667?

Comment: Not comparable as M1 macs don't run Intel Windows 10. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm not fully aware of the M1 world, does the question "What's the memory speed (reported by Windows) on Windows running on Parallels on MBP M1?"?

Answer (score 1):

The reported memory speed does not have anything to do with how fast the memory actually is.

In other words: Do not spend time trying to change the speed shown there, as changing it won't have any impact whatsoever on performance.

Comment: That's good news. Do you have a reference for such a statement?

Comment: I have developed virtualisation systems and hypervisors in the past - so I'm the reference myself. I would suggest turning the question on its head - why would the speed of the memory be affected by the reporting there? (there's no logical reason for that, so ofcourse that's not the case)